# Django Viewflow - How do apply the same transition for multiple tasks

Tags: django, django-viewflow

With viewflow, My usecase is this:
A user is assigned multiple tasks. He wants to select some of the task and apply the same transition(Approve/Reject) to them. How can he do this?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing specific. Just to activate and complete activation per-task. For safety reasons, you need to pre `.select_for_update` all included processes.

```
Process.objects.filter(...).select_for_update()
for task in _list_of_tasks_:
   activation = task.activate()
   activation.prepare()
   # do something
   # activation.process.approved = False
   # activation.process.save()
   activation.done()
```